# ggplot2 heatmaps: using different gradients for categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This Learning R blog post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) shows how to make a heatmap of basketball stats using ggplot2. The finished heatmap looks like this:

[image]

My question (inspired by [Jake](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/#comment-450) who commented on the Learning R blog post) is: would it be possible to use different gradient colors for different categories of stats (offensive, defensive, other)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First, recreate the graph from the post, updating it for the newer (0.9.2.1) version of `ggplot2` which has a different theme system and attaches fewer packages:

```
nba <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv")
nba$Name <- with(nba, reorder(Name, PTS))

library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
library("scales")

nba.m <- melt(nba)
nba.s <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform,
               rescale = scale(value))

ggplot(nba.s, aes(variable, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue") + 
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 9) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Using different gradient colors for different categories is not all that straightforward. The conceptual approach, to map the `fill` to `interaction(rescale, Category)` (where `Category` is Offensive/Defensive/Other; see below) doesn't work because interacting a factor and continuous variable gives a discrete variable which `fill` can not be mapped to.

The way to get around this is to artificially do this interaction, mapping `rescale` to non-overlapping ranges for different values of `Category` and then use `scale_fill_gradientn` to map each of these regions to different color gradients.

First create the categories. I think these map to those in the comment, but I'm not sure; changing which variable is in which category is easy.

```
nba.s$Category <- nba.s$variable
levels(nba.s$Category) <- 
  list("Offensive" = c("PTS", "FGM", "FGA", "X3PM", "X3PA", "AST"),
       "Defensive" = c("DRB", "ORB", "STL"),
       "Other" = c("G", "MIN", "FGP", "FTM", "FTA", "FTP", "X3PP", 
                   "TRB", "BLK", "TO", "PF"))
```

Since `rescale` is within a few (3 or 4) of 0, the different categories can be offset by a hundred to keep them separate. At the same time, determine where the endpoints of each color gradient should be, in terms of both rescaled values and colors.

```
nba.s$rescaleoffset <- nba.s$rescale + 100*(as.numeric(nba.s$Category)-1)
scalerange <- range(nba.s$rescale)
gradientends <- scalerange + rep(c(0,100,200), each=2)
colorends <- c("white", "red", "white", "green", "white", "blue")
```

Now replace the `fill` variable with `rescaleoffset` and change the `fill` scale to use `scale_fill_gradientn` (remembering to rescale the values):

```
ggplot(nba.s, aes(variable, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescaleoffset), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colorends, values = rescale(gradientends)) + 
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 9) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Reordering to get related stats together is another application of the `reorder` function on the various variables:

```
nba.s$variable2 <- reorder(nba.s$variable, as.numeric(nba.s$Category))

ggplot(nba.s, aes(variable2, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescaleoffset), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colorends, values = rescale(gradientends)) + 
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 9) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would one then assign different colors to the players instead (i.e. to the rows instead of the columns)?

Comment: Same general concept; make an offset scaled variable which is a function of the original scaling variable and `as.numeric(NAME)`. Then tease out the endpoints of the various ranges. But I think that would be a bad idea because your comparisons are columnwise; using different colors (that is, parts of different gradients) makes elements not comparable within a column.

Comment: This is very useful indeed. Any clue on how to put a legend on this? That would definitely complete the picture!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simpler suggestion that uses ggplot2 aesthetics to map both gradients as well as color categories. Simply use an alpha-aesthetic to generate the gradient, and the fill-aesthetic for the category.

Here is the code to do so, refactoring Brian Diggs' response:

```
nba <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv")
nba$Name <- with(nba, reorder(Name, PTS))

library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
library("scales")

nba.m <- melt(nba)
nba.s <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform,
           rescale = scale(value))

nba.s$Category <- nba.s$variable
levels(nba.s$Category) <- list("Offensive" = c("PTS", "FGM", "FGA", "X3PM", "X3PA", "AST"),
   "Defensive" = c("DRB", "ORB", "STL"),
   "Other" = c("G", "MIN", "FGP", "FTM", "FTA", "FTP", "X3PP", "TRB", "BLK", "TO", "PF"))
```

Then, normalise the `rescale` variable to between 0 and 1:

```
nba.s$rescale = (nba.s$rescale-min(nba.s$rescale))/(max(nba.s$rescale)-min(nba.s$rescale))
```

And now, do the plotting:

```
ggplot(nba.s, aes(variable, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = rescale, fill=Category), colour = "white") + 
  scale_alpha(range=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete("", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 9) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot2 heatmap using alpha aesthetic]

Note the use of `alpha=rescale` and then the scaling of the alpha range using `scale_alpha(range=c(0,1))`, which can be adapted to change the range appropriately for your plot.