# Draw heatmap tiles for all combination of x-y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I asked a question about the heatmap which was solved here: [custom colored heatmap of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213961/custom-colored-heatmap-of-categorical-variables/46214312?noredirect=1#comment79399190_46214312). I defined my `scale_fill_manual` for all combinations as suggested in the accepted answer.

Based on this question, I would like to know how to tell `ggplot2` to plot a heatmap with all combination of variables and not just the ones that are available in the dataframe (given that they are already in the `scale_fill_manual` but are not showing in the final plot).

How can I do this?

The current plotting code:

```
df <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:3], 
                 Likelihood = c("Almost Certain","Likely","Possible"), 
                 Impact = c("Catastrophic", "Major","Moderate"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$color <- paste0(df$Likelihood,"-",df$Impact)

ggplot(df, aes(Impact, Likelihood)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = color),colour = "white") + geom_text(aes(label=X)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Almost Certain-Catastrophic" = "red","Likely-Major" = "yellow","Possible-Moderate" = "blue"))
```

scale_fill_manual contains all combination of `Impact, Likelihood` with their respective colors.

Comment: have a look at the `GGally` package.

Comment: so you basically want all remaining tiles, for which there are no values, to be the same color (e.g., grey?)

Comment: Could you add your current code to the question?  One solution might be to expand the dataset to encompass all combinations of `Likelihood` and `Impact` prior to plotting with, e.g., `tidyr::complete`.

Comment: no not the same color, basically based on the manual fill scale I provide for each combination @timfaber

Comment: @aosmith code added

Comment: I don't see a fill color for every possible combination of `Likelihood` and `Impact`.  What should the other fill colors be?

Comment: @aosmith yes, its because the list is too long to put here. But there is a color for each combination

Comment: In that case, my idea above should work.  You can expand your dataset so all combinations of the two variables are present prior to making the `fill` variable and plotting.  That task of expanding the dataset is fairly straightforward with`tidyr::complete`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @aosmith I tried `expand.grid` to get a finite set of combinations but `tidyr::complete()` works pretty nice as well. Add the colors and letters and fill using a set color range.

```
df <- data.frame(Likelihood = c("Almost Certain","Likely","Possible"), 
                 Impact = c("Catastrophic", "Major","Moderate"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- df %>% tidyr::complete(Likelihood,Impact) # alt expand.grid(df)

df2$X <- LETTERS[1:9] # Add letters here
df2$color <- paste0(df2$Likelihood,"-",df2$Impact) # Add colors


ggplot(df2, aes(Impact, Likelihood)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = color),colour = "white") + geom_text(aes(label=X)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,"Pastel1"))
```